# Toolbar Done Button Disappears After Presenting and Dismissing Alert in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, toolbar

The issue is that I added a toolbar "Done" button, but when I present an alert on the same view and then refocus on the text field, the toolbar "Done" button disappears automatically in SwiftUI. In `TitleWithTextfield`, there is a text field and a label. I've implemented validations; for instance, if the text field is empty and the user taps on the submit button, an alert is displayed prompting the user to enter their name or email. However, after the user presses the "OK" button and then taps on the text field again, the toolbar's "Done" button disappears automatically.

Here's the code:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            AppColors.primaryColor
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            
                VStack {
                    
                    NavigationViewWithTitleInCenter(title: "Feedback", backButtonAction: {
                        // Call your function here
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        print("Back button tapped!")
                    })
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    VStack {
                        
                        TitleWithTextfield(placeholder: "Enter Name", text: $name)
                        
                        TitleWithTextfield(placeholder: "Enter Email", text: $email)
                        
                        TitleWithTextfield(placeholder: "Enter Subject", text: $subject)
                        
                        TitleWithTextView(placeholder: "Enter Message", text: $description)
                        
                        PrimaryButton(title: "Submit").onTapGesture {
                            self.didTapSubmit()
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .toolbar {
                        
                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                            Spacer()
                            Button("Done") {
                                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                            }
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
                    }
                                   

                    Spacer()
                }
           

                .blur(radius: isLoading ? 1 : 0) // Apply blur when isLoading is true
                .loadingOverlay(isLoading: isLoading)


        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Message"), message: Text("\(alertMessage)"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] that I can just copy and paste into my Xcode and reproduce the problem? Can you replace `TitleWithTextView`, `NavigationViewWithTitleInCenter` etc with something built-in that also reproduces the problem? Or show their declarations too.

Comment: Hello @Sweeper , I have created a sample project and attempted to replicate the same functionality using just a text field and a basic alert, and it worked perfectly there. Thank you for your suggestion. I believe there may be another issue within my code, but it's quite lengthy, so I can't share all of it. Thanks again.